# Как написать консольное взаимодействие с программой в линуксе?

Tags: linux

Что я имею ввиду, я хочу чтобы взаимодействие выходило за рамки обычного вызова ее командой => алиасы и path мне особо не помогают

хочу добиться чего то такого:

`tst` - вызов чего то в духе списка команд

`tst <команда>` - выполнение этой команды

`tst <send/get> <имя файла>` - отправить/притащить файлы с сервера (файлов может быть несколько, прям как при `npm i <pkg1> <pkg2> <pkg3>`)

Как это сделать и что примерно гуглить?

Comment: [Читайте](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Basics.html)

Comment: и вот тут для быстрого старта https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%89%D1%82+%D1%84%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%B7%D1%84%D0%BA%D1%8B%D1%83&oq=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%89%D1%82+%D1%84%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%B7%D1%84%D0%BA%D1%8B%D1%83